# usb3 case with ssd: extremely weird behaviour

Tags: usb, ssd, external-disk, case

I have an iMac Retina 2017 (and a Mini, 2014) running Mojave and Sierra respectively. I had a spare Samsung 850 EVO (250 GB) SSD from another computer that is dying. I got a new USB3 case from Amazon (Orico). Fitted the SSD and plugged it in. Weirdness begins.

1. Wouldn't show up in Finder, Disk Utility, Terminal (diskutil).
2. Unplugged and replugged. Showed up once allowed me to reformat it.
3. Ejected and wouldn't show up again.
4. Tested on both machines. Same problem.
5. Placed the SSD in an old USB2 case. Mounted and worked without an issue.
6. Placed an old 160GB HDD in the USB3 case. Mounted and worked without an issue.
7. Tested the USB3/SSD combo again: wouldn't mount.
8. Changed the USB3 cable with a cable from a Seagate 2TB, 2.5" drive mounted. Allowed me to install Mojave. And then halfway through installing apps, it hung. Hard reboot of iMac.
9. Tried plugging into the Mini. Mouse cursor disappeared!

My conclusions:
the case works, the drive works, the cable works. They just don't work together.

I would be very grateful for any help or pointers.
I've already returned one case because it went through these issues.
Thank you
Ashok

Comment: the SSD could be dying, also the USB case could be incompatible/defective. At least try a different brand of case.

Comment: It’s not clear what your expectations are with respect to Apple/macOS.  You’ve *positively* identified that the issue is the USB3 case/cable (see #4 & #5).  There’s nothing that macOS can do to make an enclosure or it’s cable function properly.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has, through own diagnostics, has determined the issue is with 3rd party hardware and not with Apple/macOS

Comment: I would connect the EVO to another computer with SATA and run extensive SMART tests using Smartmontools so you can get all the details in depth. The SSD may be failing.  You might not have run extensive usage patters with it connected as USB2 as well. Seemed to be working with the cable from the Seagate but then hung after awhile.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you everyone who responded to my question. I finally got a USB3 to SATA adapter cable and tried it. Worked fine. Thank you James for that suggestion. I think there is some incompatibility between the case or its cable and a Mac. Thanks again